# Dudas varias con div

Tags: jquery, html, html5, css

Tengo una página en la que la cabecera y el pie de página siempre es estático, solo cambia el cuerpo al presionar unos botones.

El caso es que tengo la página principal, me falta hacer los distintos divs del contenido que quiero cambiar.

Tengo dos preguntas:

1. ¿Cómo hago para que cuando presione un botón aparezca un div u otro?
2. ¿Creo todos los div en el mismo index.html o creo cada archivo html y meto el contenido de lo que quiero que salga en vez de todos los div en el mismo index.html?

Comment: Esta pregunta va a atraer respuestas basadas en opiniones en lugar de en hechos y referencias. Intenta añadir más información para concretar más y que sea más específica: ¿qué tipo de contenido va a tener el sitio?¿es dinámico o estático?¿cómo de grande es cada sección? etc. Dependiendo de las respuestas se podrá hacer una valoración más objetiva

Comment: Porque tengo -1 en mi respuesta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes añadir todos los div en un mismo archivo .html y luego con jquery puedes hacer que aparezcan y desaparezcan cuando quieras. Te indico un ejemplo:

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();//Esta función oculta la etiqueta p
});

$("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();//Esta función muestra la etiqueta p
});
```

Espero que sirva

Comment: Porque me han dado -1 a esta respuesta??

Comment: Gracuas a todos, al final  me sirvio la respuesta de Alberto Mier.
He intentado darte +1 pero no me deja por la experiencia.
Algun envidioso te la habrá bajado

Comment: Buena respuesta @AlbertoMier un +1 Algún día puede que lo use

Comment: Aunque no le puedas dar el +1 si te ha servido la respuesta de @AlbertoMier le puedes dar el visto bueno a su respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear los div en el mismo html, con distinto nombre de ID, luego por jquery, podrás indicar a través del botón el div a mostar o a ocultar.
HTML

```
<div class="btnmenu" id="menua">            
                <div style="cursor:pointer;border:none;"><h2><img class="img" id="imga" src="imagenes/mas.png"/><h2>&nbsp;TITULO</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div id="obsa" class="obs"  style=" display:none;">
            xxxxxxxxxx
            </div>
            <div class="btnmenu" id="menub">            
                <div  style="cursor:pointer;border:none;"><h2><img class="img" id="imgb" src="imagenes/mas.png"/><h2>&nbsp;TITULO</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div id="obsb" class="obs"  style="display:none;"> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

EL JS sería

```
$("div.btnmenu").click(function(){
        id=this.id.substr(4, 1);

        valor=$("img#img"+id).attr("src");
        $("div.obs").slideUp("normal");
        $("img.img").attr("src","imagenes/mas.png" );
        $("div#obs"+id+":hidden").slideDown("normal");
        if (valor=="imagenes/mas.png")
        {
            $("img#img"+id).attr("src","imagenes/menos.png" );

        }
        else
        {
            $("img#img"+id).attr("src","imagenes/mas.png" );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de código de como hacerlo?